# Correlogram in R like in Stata?

Tags: r, time-series, data-visualization, autocorrelation

In STATA I can create a "Correlogram" to find the appropriate lag order in case of time series. E.g.
[image: corrgram]

I know I can use the acf or Acf of the forecast package to calculate the ACF and PACF and to plot it. But how can I get the significance values? I mean the values in the column Prob>Q? Is this implemented in any package/command?

Comment: Question refers to `corrgram` command in Stata [NB correct spelling] in which the hypothesis being tested is white noise. There is a Stata command `ac` to plot the acf in more civilised fashion. (Not an answer, clearly; just adding a little context.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can calculate the threshold significance for a given coefficient.  To check this, I just did a quick google search.  Found this https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2009-August/207266.html The code to make the calculation is below.  I hope this helps.

```
dev.new(height=6, width=4.5)
par(mfrow=c(2,1), mar=c(3,4,0.5,0.5))

testAR1 <- arima.sim(n=300, list(ar=c(0.5)))
test_acf <- acf(testAR1)
test_acf_CritVal <- qnorm((1 + 0.95)/2)/sqrt(test_acf$n.used) #change the 0.95 to the desired CI
abline(h=test_acf_CritVal, col="red") #add the calculated CI to the plot, just to check that it goes in the right spot

test_pacf <- pacf(testAR1)
test_pacf_CritVal <- qnorm((1 + 0.95)/2)/sqrt(test_pacf$n.used) #change the 0.95 to the desired CI
abline(h=test_pacf_CritVal, col="red") #add the calculated CI to the plot, just to check that it goes in the right spot
```

Now that you have the critical value, you can now compare that to the estimated coefficients for the different lags.

```
Test_acf_lags <- as.vector(test_acf$lag)
Test_acf_coefs <- as.vector(test_acf$acf)
Test_acf_Signif <- as.integer(Test_acf_coefs>test_acf_CritVal)

Test_pacf_lags <- as.vector(test_pacf$lag)
Test_pacf_coefs <- as.vector(test_pacf$acf)
Test_pacf_Signif <- as.integer(Test_pacf_coefs>test_pacf_CritVal)

R_Correlo_Table_acf <- data.frame("Lag"=Test_acf_lags, "acf"=Test_acf_coefs, "Signif_acf"=Test_acf_Signif)
R_Correlo_Table_pacf <- data.frame("Lag"=Test_pacf_lags, "pacf"=Test_pacf_coefs, "Signif_pacf"=Test_pacf_Signif)
R_Correlo_Table <- merge(R_Correlo_Table_acf, R_Correlo_Table_pacf, all=TRUE)

print(R_Correlo_Table)
```

EDIT: Added the calculation and plotting of confidence bands for model ID

```
dev.new(height=6, width=4.5)
par(mfrow=c(2,1), mar=c(3,4,0.5,0.5))

Nsim <- 100
test2AR1 <- arima.sim(n=Nsim, list(ar=c(0.85)))
test2_acf <- acf(test2AR1, ylim=c(-1,1))
Nlag <- length(test2_acf$lag)
Bart_se_acf_frist <- 1/sqrt(Nsim)
Bart_se_acf_rest <- sqrt((1+2*cumsum(test2_acf$acf^2)[-Nlag])/Nsim)
Bart_se_acf <- c(Bart_se_acf_frist, Bart_se_acf_rest)
ConfBands <- qnorm((1-0.05/2)) * Bart_se_acf
lines(test2_acf$lag, ConfBands, col="red") #add the calculated CI to the plot, just to check that it goes in the right spot
lines(test2_acf$lag, ConfBands*-1, col="red")


test2_pacf <- pacf(test2AR1, ylim=c(-1,1))
Nlag <- length(test2_pacf$lag)
Bart_se_pacf_frist <- 1/sqrt(Nsim)
Bart_se_pacf_rest <- sqrt((1+2*cumsum(test2_pacf$acf^2)[-Nlag])/Nsim)
Bart_se_pacf <- c(Bart_se_pacf_frist, Bart_se_pacf_rest)
ConfBands <- qnorm((1-0.05/2)) * Bart_se_pacf
lines(test2_pacf$lag, ConfBands, col="red") #add the calculated CI to the plot, just to check that it goes in the right spot
lines(test2_pacf$lag, ConfBands*-1, col="red")
```

Comment: thanks a lot, but in the first part, in the command abline(h=test_CritVal...... I get the error message: "Object 'test_CritVal' nicht not found"?

Comment: this should be "test_acf_CritVal" or?

Comment: One big question: I want to fit an ARMA, so I don't want to test for randomness, so I need the correct confidence bands, which increase with the lag order, see wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlogram How can I get those?

Comment: Ah, thanks for finding that error.  You were correct in your correction, and I edited the answer to contain the correct code.  If I correctly understand (a) your question, and (b) the wiki graph, I think the only difference between what you want and the graph in the code I provided is the change in sample size due to a change in lag.  Basically, you "lose" one observation per order of lag.  Because sample size takes the form of `sqrt(n)`, if the range of lags being explored is small relative to the sample size, the CI's won't change much. But let me try calculating what you want.

Comment: I made edits to the answer --- does that give what you want?  I just used the equations on the wiki page.

Comment: thank you very much for your help, but I think it is not that easy, see here on page 82: http://www.stata.com/bookstore/stata11/pdf/ts_corrgram.pdf I don't think that it is just about loosing one observation per order of lag. See the text below the formula on page 82 . But thanks anyway for your help!

Comment: and I also think, that this is only the case in ACF. If you look at the PACF it seems, that people do not use Bartlett's formula, but the "normal", the constant, bands. Mh, but I don't know why....

Comment: @StatTistician You're right about the N-1 one thing -- For the code, I ended up using a formula from the wiki site, which was different from what I had originally said in that comment.  As for the pacf, I get the coefficients from what R computs (`pacf(...)$acf`, so that seems like it should give the right value.  But I confess that I'm working through this with you, so I could be wrong.  Sorry I couldn't be of more help, and thanks for talking about the topic with me.

Comment: First of all thanks. Yeah you take the pacf values in your code, but I mean in general: You do not use Bartlett if you look at the PACF, only if you look at the ACF. Looking at the PACF people seem to use the normal confidence bands. But I don't know why......

Comment: Interesting point.  You add up the squares of the acf's b/c they're serially correlated --- pacf is supposed to remove this serial dependence.  Perhaps when that's the case, you can just use the normal bands.  However, if there's an MA term in the model, then the pacf will behave similarly to the acf in a strictly AR model, right?  Again, I don't know the answer, just taking a stab at the logic.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the extract from the p.16 and corresponding code from p. 17 of the book by [Bernhard Pfaff](http://books.google.com/books/about/Analysis_of_integrated_and_cointegrated.html?id=ca5MkRbF3fYC) which answers your question:

The assumption of uncorrelatedness can be tested with the `Ljung-Box Portmanteau` test (see Ljung and Box [1978]). This test is implemented in the `Box.test()` function of the package `stat`.Except for the PACF, these tools are graphically returned by the function `tsdiag()`. Note in the following code `y` is the variable of an interest (e.g, GDP or unemployment rate).

```
## ARMA ( 1 , 1 )
arma11 <− arima(y , order = c(1, 0, 1) )
tsdiag(arma11)
res11 <− residuals (arma11)
Box . test ( res11 , lag = 20, type = ”Ljung−Box ”)
tsdiag(arma11)
```

Comment: but this does already imply I fitted an arma11 model!? I want to do this diagnostics before fitting, it does not have to do with the residuals. I want to do this before model estimation, to check the significance of the serial dependence and to identify the correct model.

Answer (score 0):

I have written an implementation that is identical to STATA. `plot = TRUE` gives a plot. Happy if someone maintaining a time-series package would like to include it.

```
corrgrm <- function(x, lag.max = NULL, plot = FALSE) {
  if(plot) {
    oldpar <- par(mfrow = c(1, 2))
    on.exit(par(oldpar))
  }
  ac <- eval(substitute(acf(x, lag.max, plot = plot)))
  acf <- drop(ac[[1L]])[-1]
  pacf <- drop(eval(substitute(pacf(x, lag.max, plot = plot)))[[1L]])
  n <- ac$n.used
  # n * cumsum(acf^2) Box Pierce -> poor small sample properties
  qstat <- n * (n + 2) * cumsum(acf^2 / seq.int(n - 1, n - length(acf))) # Ljung-Box: The standard: Same as STATA !!
  lags <- seq_along(acf)
  res <- cbind(Lag = lags, AC = acf, PAC = pacf,
               Q = qstat, `Pr(>Q)` = pchisq(qstat, lags, lower.tail = FALSE))
  class(res) <- "corrgrm"
  res
}

print.corrgrm <- function(x, digits = 3, ...) {
  xx <- cbind(format(x[, 1L, drop = FALSE], drop0trailing = TRUE),
              format(round(x[, -1L], digits)))
  print.default(`rownames<-`(xx, rep(" ", nrow(xx))), quote = FALSE, right = TRUE)
}
```